# Undefined method '.any?' for "":String (NoMethodError

Tags: ruby, any

```
def room_actions    
  case $next_move
  when "instructions"
    instructions
  when $next_move.any? { |x| ['up', 'down', 'left', 'right'].include?(x) }
    determine_start
  else 
    puts "I don't understand that."
    prompt; $next_move = gets.chomp()
    room_actions
  end
end
```

Forgive me for not understanding what's going on here, but why is ruby throwing this error?

> foo.rb:83:in `room_actions': undefined method`any?' for "":String (NoMethodError)

`$next_move` is a global variable (I know they're bad, I'm refactoring) that I feed into this method from a gets chomp in a state machine.

It seems that I'm failing to define the 'any?' method. Or that the string I'm passing is empty? Anyway, isn't '.any?' a built in ruby method? I'm using 2.0.0.

Thank you for taking a look and advising.

Answer (score 5):

Strings (empty or not) don't have an `any?` method (enumerable such as arrays or hashes do. Strings were enumerable in ruby 1.8 but are no longer so).

It's very unclear to me why you are trying to call `.any?` on it in the first place - if you want to check whether it is one of that list of allowable values then

```
['up','down','left','right'].include?($next_move)
```

Will do the job

Comment: Ah ha! THAT'S why it doesn't work. I wrote it in 1.8.7 and am now running it in 2.0.0! I KNEW I wasn't crazy! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error message

```
undefined method `any?' for "":String
```

means you are trying to call `any?` on a `String`. The `any?` method, however, is only defined on `Enumerable` (and thus on collections like `Array` and `Hash`)

Answer (score 0):

any? method is for arrays.
do just:
`['up', 'down', 'left', 'right'].include?($next_move)`